# Android Paging v3 with just local Room database: how do I scroll to specific position in a paged list?

Tags: android, scroll, android-room, android-paging

I'm not sure if this is the correct use case for [Paging v3](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-paged-data) but here goes.

All my data is in a local Room database (no network calls, no APIs). I have a potentially large data set of todo-lists (one for each date). I have a RecyclerView that displays these todo-lists to the user. Obviously, I don't want to load all the todo-lists for the user so I chose to go with a paged data source and decided to use Paging v3.

I followed [this youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BwUblMTiUo8) for my paging implementation.

**I got everything working for a basic use case, but now I'm stuck. I want to let the user jump to a specific date in the list. I also want to listen if they scroll to a new date and create a new todo-list for them.**

I'm not sure how to scroll my RecyclerView or paged source to a specific point in the list.

My Dao:

```
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM todo_list ORDER BY date DESC")
    fun loadTodoListsPaged(): PagingSource<Int, TodoList>
```

My View Model:

```
class TodoListViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val todoListsPaged = Pager(PagingConfig(
            pageSize = 10,
            enablePlaceholders = false,
            maxSize = 30
    )) {
        myTodoListDao.loadTodoListsPaged()
    }.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
}
```

My Adapter:

```
class TodoListPagingDataAdapter(
    val context: Context
): PagingDataAdapter<TodoList, TodoListViewHolder>(TodoListDiffUtilCallback()) {

...

}
```

I'm not sure if this is possible because `Room only supports PagingSource with Key of type Int.`

**Using [Paging v3](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-paged-data), how do I jump or scroll to a specific point in the list?**

Ideally, I'd just pass something the date and it would tell me the page I need. Then I pass the page to the adapter/recyclerview/pager and it loads it for me.

**Update**

I just ended up storing a mutable list of dates as LiveData and used a Transformation Switch Map to map that to my todo lists (passing in the list of dates to the database and getting associated lists back). As the user scrolls, I add/remove dates from this mutable list and it automatically updates. It worked a lot better than the paging and was much more simple. If anyone wants more details, just ask.

Comment: - I'm much more interested in your latest approach. Can you please elaborate your Transformation Switch and passing the query to the database and getting desired result back. Will be helpful.

Comment: I've added an answer with more details. @Anupam

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a way to jump based on a specific value in the adapted data.
If an answer is posted saying otherwise more power to you.

If you can't find away to use the PagingSource I think I may have a solution.

When the user enters a date programmatically scroll through the list until you find it.

```
fun scrollTilFindDate(date : Date, offset : Int){
    var dateFound : Boolean = false;
    var todos: List<Todo> = adapter.snapshot().items;
    for(todo : Todo in todos){
       if(todo.date == date){
          dateFound = true;
          break;
       }
    }
    if(!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1) || dateFound){
        return;
    }else{
        var newOffset : Int = offset+pageSize;
        recyclerView.post(()->{
              recyclerView.scrollToPosition(newOffset);
              scrollTilFindDate(date,newOffset);  
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone asked for more details about my alternative solution. This solution was easy and worked well for my needs. I could jump to any date by changing the ViewModel's current date and it would automatically load other dates around that date (according to the paging config settings).

My RecyclerView only showed 1 item at a time. I used the `SnapOnScrollListener`'s `onSnapPositionReadyToSnap` to update the ViewModel's current date and trigger the dates to load.

Depending on how you order the dates (ASC vs DESC) and depending on if your RecyclerView has `reverseLayout` set to true, the loadNextPage / loadPrevPage may be backwards for you. So keep that in mind.

**ViewModel**

This contains most of the logic & probably could be split up. It does the heavy lifting to facilitate loading items by date.

```
// NOTE: taskListRepository is just a wrapper for my Room DAOs. 

class MyViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    
    val selectedDateLive = MutableLiveData(LocalDate.now())
    var selectedDate get() = selectedDateLive.value
        set(value) { selectedDateLive.value = value }

    // I used Android's paging config as my own config, but I did NOT use paging itself
    private val pageConfigForDates = PagingConfig(
        pageSize = 10, // how many to load in each page
        prefetchDistance = 3, // how far from the end before we should load more; defaults to page size
        initialLoadSize = 10, // how many items should we initially load; defaults to 3x page size
        maxSize = 16 // how many items do we keep in memory; defaults to unlimited (must be > pageSize + 2*prefetchDistance)
    )

    private var datesLoaded: List<LocalDate> = emptyList()

    private val datesToLoadLive = Transformations.switchMap(selectedDateLive) { currentDate ->
        val indexOfCurrent = datesLoaded.indexOf(currentDate)

        // initial dates
        if (datesLoaded.isEmpty() || indexOfCurrent == -1) {
            val initialDates = getDatesAround(currentDate, pageConfigForDates.initialLoadSize)
            datesLoaded = initialDates
            ensureListsExistForDates(initialDates)
            return@switchMap MutableLiveData(datesLoaded)
        }

        // previous dates
        val shouldLoadPreviousPage = indexOfCurrent < pageConfigForDates.prefetchDistance
        if (shouldLoadPreviousPage) {
            val pastDates = getPastDates(datesLoaded.first(), pageConfigForDates.pageSize)
            datesLoaded = pastDates.plus(datesLoaded).take(pageConfigForDates.maxSize)
            ensureListsExistForDates(pastDates)
            return@switchMap MutableLiveData(datesLoaded)
        }

        // next dates
        val shouldLoadNextPage = (datesLoaded.count() - indexOfCurrent) < pageConfigForDates.prefetchDistance
        if (shouldLoadNextPage) {
            val futureDates = getFutureDates(datesLoaded.last(), pageConfigForDates.pageSize)
            datesLoaded = datesLoaded.plus(futureDates).takeLast(pageConfigForDates.maxSize)
            ensureListsExistForDates(futureDates)
            return@switchMap MutableLiveData(datesLoaded)
        }

        return@switchMap MutableLiveData(datesLoaded)
    }
    
    private fun getPastDates(date: LocalDate, numberOfDays: Int): List<LocalDate> {
        return (numberOfDays downTo 1L).map { date.minusDays(it) }
    }

    private fun getDatesAround(date: LocalDate, numberOfDays: Int): List<LocalDate> {
        val halfNumberOfDays = numberOfDays / 2
        val counter = ((-halfNumberOfDays..0L) + (1L..halfNumberOfDays)).takeLast(numberOfDays)
        return counter.map { date.plusDays(it) }.toList()
    }

    private fun getFutureDates(date: LocalDate, numberOfDays: Int): List<LocalDate> {
        return (1L..numberOfDays).map { date.plusDays(it) }
    }

    private fun ensureListsExistForDates(dates: List<LocalDate>) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val items = taskListRepository.getTaskListsWithTasksForDates(dates)
            if (items.count() < pageConfigForDates.pageSize) {
                val missingDates = dates.minus(items.map { it.taskList.date })
                taskListRepository.createTaskLists(missingDates)
            }
        }
    }

    private val taskListsFromDatesLive = Transformations.distinctUntilChanged(datesToLoadLive).switchMap { dates ->
        taskListRepository.getTaskListsWithTasksForDatesLive(dates!!)
    }

}
```

**DAO for accessing DB**

```
@Dao
interface TaskListWithTasksDao {

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM task_list WHERE date IN (:dates) ORDER BY date DESC")
    suspend fun getTaskListWithTasksForDates(dates: List<LocalDate>): List<TaskListWithTasks>

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM task_list WHERE date IN (:dates) ORDER BY date DESC")
    fun getTaskListWithTasksForDatesLive(dates: List<LocalDate>): LiveData<List<TaskListWithTasks>>
}
```

**Data class (for the foreign key relationship)**

```
data class TaskListWithTasks(
    @Embedded
    var taskList: TaskList = TaskList(),

    @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "task_list_id", entity = TaskListItem::class)
    var tasks: List<TaskListItem> = emptyList()
)
```